# SQL: How to search set datatype by array?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if the data exist in `set datatype` by using an array.

For example:
The table is

```
id  role
1   'a'
2   'b'
3   'a','b','c'
```

$role = ['a']

SQL = `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE $role in role` (have 'a')

And the result is

```
id  role
1   'a'
3   'a','b','c'
```

Or
$role = ['a','b']

SQL = `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE $role in role` (have 'a' and 'b')

And the result is

```
id  role
3   'a','b','c'
```

I tried to use `FIND_IN_SET(('a','b'),role)>0;` but it's not work. I need to use a loop.
Have any method better than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have an array type. What you are using is a string, that happens to contain commas.

The better method in a relational database is to store multi-valued attributes in a second table, with one value per row.

```
CREATE TABLE role (
  entity_id INT NOT NULL,
  role CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(entity_id, role),
  FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES mytable (id)
);

INSERT INTO role VALUES
(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c');
```

If you need to find an entry that has both role 'a' and role 'b', this is called [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). There are several solutions when using a normalized table. Here's one:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM mytable 
JOIN role AS r1 ON mytable.id = r1.entity_id
JOIN role AS r2 ON mytable.id = r2.entity_id
WHERE r1.role = 'a' AND r2.role = 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Bill Karwin for a trick.
Now I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`user_role` (
    `userId` INT NOT NULL,
    `a` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    `b` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and `view table` that connects the `user table` and `role table`.